# Nash Equilibrium for duopoly

Tags: microeconomics

Could someone please verify my answer to the following question:
"Coop and Migros form a duopoly in the Swiss retail market. This is a direct consequence of the surge in oil prices during the third and fourth quarters of 2021. Both companies are considering changing their pricing policies for cooking oil. The following payoff matrix indicates the annual profits of these companies for all combinations of pricing strategies (in millions of CHF). What is the Nash equilibrium, is it Pareto efficient?"
My answer : Nash equilibrium is (Low Price, Low Price) and it is pareto efficient. As, Migros would sell at a lower price than Coop would.
[image]

Comment: Hint: $6>5$ and $7>6$.

Comment: So (6,7) is pareto efficient and (5,6) which is the nash equilibrium is pareto optimal as they'd cooperate and reduce output to drive up the price ?

Comment: Pareto efficient and Pareto optimal mean the same thing. The unique NE is not Pareto efficient.